# MVC3 ReCaptcha with Fluent Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, recaptcha, fluentvalidation, mvcrecaptcha

I'm trying to validate ReCaptcha using FluentValidation but I'm having some issues. Even though the ReCaptcha.Validate returns true the ModelState is not valid. In order to validate the ReCaptcha I added a field in the view model. Before checking to see if the ModelState is valid I set the ReCaptcha field to whatever is returned from ReCaptcha.Validate.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Index(Over18Model model)
    {
        model.ReCaptcha = Microsoft.Web.Helpers.ReCaptcha.Validate("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var table = new Prospect();
            dynamic o = new ExpandoObject();
            {
                o.FirstName = model.FirstName;
                o.LastName = model.LastName;
                o.Email = model.Email;
            }
            table.Save(o);
            return RedirectToAction("ThankYou", "Public");
        }
        ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Errors:  " + string.Join(" ; ", ModelState.Values.SelectMany(x => x.Errors).Select(x => x.ErrorMessage)));
        return View(model); 
    }

    [Validator(typeof(Over18ModelValidator))]
    public class Over18Model
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public bool ReCaptcha { get; set; }
    }

    public class Over18ModelValidator : AbstractValidator<Over18Model>
    {
        public Over18ModelValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.FirstName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("First Name is Required");
            RuleFor(x => x.LastName).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Last Name is Required");
            RuleFor(x => x.Email).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email is Required");
            RuleFor(x => x.Email).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email");
            RuleFor(x => x.ReCaptcha).Equal(true).WithMessage("ReCaptcha error");
        }
    }
```

The Razor code looks like this...

```
<div class="signUpOver18">
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()         
        @Form.TextBox(name: "FirstName", value: @Model.FirstName, labelText: "First Name:", containerClass: "fname", txtfldClass: "standard names", maxLength: 50) 
        @Form.TextBox(name: "LastName", value: @Model.LastName, labelText: "Last Name:", containerClass: "lname", txtfldClass: "standard names", maxLength: 100) 
        </div>
        @Form.Submit(value: "Enter The Sweepstakes", myClass: "btnSubmit")

        <div class="recaptchaHolder">
            @ReCaptcha.GetHtml(theme: "red", publicKey: "XXX-XXXX_XXXX-XX_") 
        </div>

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)  
    }
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not mandatory to use fluentvalidation for validating captcha...try the microsoft web helpers..it works perfectly..